# How do I get an Atheros AR9287 working?

Tags: 11.04, networking, atheros

I'm running Windows 7 normally on my Acer laptop, and it works like a charm. However, whenever I boot up Ubuntu, the network card doesn't even seem to exist.

I've looked for hours for a solution, to no avail.

These are some specs of the chip:

```
Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

What steps do I have to take to get some kind of network connection? The networking was the one thing I liked about Ubuntu, however, this is kind of a turn-off.

I have tried running the "Additional Drivers" tool but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the ethernet and running "additional drivers"?

Comment: I don't know what "additional drivers" is, but I will go try that.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and I get no results. It updated my Natty, but no change in network status. Is there a place where I could get a driver? Or how could I use ndiswrapper?

Answer (score 2):

Googling around - as you have found, some of the Atheros drivers in the 2.6.38 kernel are broken.

This [website](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=919065) suggests the following workaround until the kernel is fixed:

```
sudo su
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9.conf
```

Then reboot

Note - I've seen other websites that say that the file should be ath9k.conf.  So if the above doesnt work, try

```
sudo su
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Remove the ath9.conf / ath9k.conf file when a new kernel is released (assuming of course the new kernel fixes this issue).

Comment: Okay, I've given up at this point, but I might as well try it. I'll take it for a test spin later.

Comment: @IanVal - its perhaps also worth when testing, disabling any WEP/WPA protection you have in your router.  If you can get it working unprotected, then try enabling WEP, then WPA then WPA2 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help! For me, this line didn't work. I typed it like this: `sudo su` then `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with the solution here, which is to manually update the kernel to 3.6: [Artheros AR9287 Txpower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132012/artheros-ar9287-txpower/223747#223747)